# Celery throwing a cx_oracle error while starting workers (django, celery, redis, oracle configuration)

Tags: django, oracle, redis, celery

I am attempting to integrate celery with my running django-oracle project. Redis is configured to be the message broker and the database backend. celery settings are in the prod.py in project/settings.

When I start the workers, I get an error:

> [2023-04-26 20:35:44,049: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Signal handler <bound method DjangoWorkerFixup.on_worker_process_init of <celery.fixups.django.DjangoWorkerFixup object at 0x7fc016265f60>> raised: OperationalError(<cx_Oracle._Error object at 0x7fc009593ed8>,)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site->packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 252, in _close
> return self.connection.close()
> cx_Oracle.OperationalError: ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
> Process ID: 0

The worker runs fine, though. I can't tell where this error is generated and why.

The celery.py file looks like this:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "raxakprotect.settings.prod")                                                 
app = Celery("raxakprotect")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
```

and the CELERY_ settings in prod.py are:

```
###
# Celery related
###
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://localhost:6379"
CELERY_WORKER_SEND_TASK_EVENTS = True
CELERY_TASK_SEND_SENT_EVENT = True
```

--prasanna

Comment: Are there any relevant Oracle trace file messages on the DB side?  Do you have the file system access to add and view traces from Oracle Client libraries?

Comment: I have access to the file system. What traces in particular should I look for? The system is Oracle 21c XE on an Alma 8 OS.

Comment: There are no warnings or errors running the main wsgi/gunicorn/django/oracle process. The errors are only while starting the celery workers. Celery itself is not using the oracle backend, but using redis which is also installed.

Comment: The error you posted was from the Oracle Python driver so something seems to be connected to Oracle DB.

Comment: This has me totally stumped. Celery itself is not using Oracle (django is) as the backend. So when the worker is started there is no reason for an Oracle connection to be attempted.